# Use of suitable advice (should, should have, would, would have, must, have to)

Tags: grammar

Please tell me which is the correct one. I still don't understand about giving advice to someone. My teacher doesn't give me an explanation clearly. 
So, I need your help.

A: I have a headache. So, I can't concentrate correctly.
B: You ......... a doctor and have enough rest.

Answer 1: Should have seen
Answer 2: Must see
Answer 3: Will see
Answer 4: Would see
Answer 5: Have to see

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Okay, so the correct answer will be the Answer 1, right?

Comment: No, "should have" would mean that it was something that A was supposed to do in the past and that doesn't work with the rest of the sentence. I'm guessing it's either 2 or 5... but "have enough rest" sounds wrong to me... probably because it's British and I'm American... to avoid repeating "have", it's probably 2.

Comment: But I think we can use "should have" to speculate any events that may or may not have happened. Can you give me clear explanation? Thanks.

Comment: If I use must, then it won't be an advice. Isn't it?

Comment: Just want to add some info. I think "should have" can also be used to mention or to talk about past events that did not happen.

Comment: Yes... but it still doesn't work with the rest of the sentence... You could certainly say "You should have seen a doctor..." but the rest of the sentence would be: "... and have gotten enough rest." or something similar. It doesn't make sense with "and have enough rest"... which is talking about the future.

Answer (score 2):

As a start, "must" is used when it is an obligation from yourself:

> I must eat to survive.

But it can also be used to mean a strong advice, as :

> You must see this film, I liked it so much !!

"have to" is used when someone forces you to do something:

> I have to clean my room to go out (because my parents want me to).

"will" is simple future, so it is a fact that you will do something:

> I will work tonight (it is something I'm sure I'll do, because it is planned).

"should" is advice:

> You should work harder to succeed.

and "would" is conditional (generally with an if):

> I would be happy if I found someone.

So here, it looks like a simple advice, so, "you should see", but it is not part of your possible answers...

The problem with "should have seen" is that it is advice, but it also means that you didn't do it, and it is too late to do so.
The sentence would have been :

> You should have seen a doctor, and have had some rest

So it is an incorrect answer

So here the answer must be "must see".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But there is no answer option with "should see". Then which answer I am supposed to choose?

Comment: "Must" is used as a way to give advice, too... "You really must see *Twelfth Night*, it was wonderful!"

Comment: Yeah, I know. But it seems that "must" more like a rule or an order that you must obey. And "should" seems like a recommendation that you can accept or not. And I also want to say that should have can be used to talk or mention about past event that did not happen. Thanks, Catija!

Comment: You are right, though... "should" is actually the **best** choice, except it's not one. :(

Comment: @Catija I may have an explaination ! **Must see** may be better than **should see** if it is vital for A to be able to concentrate (if A is a pilot for instance ?). In this case, should is not strong enough...

Comment: @Random That's certainly true. There's really not enough information given in the question but I don't think we'll be getting any backstory on A and B. :P